# Create Multi Website/Stores in magento 2

Tags: magento2, multistore, magento-2.0

Can you please provide the source/procedures to create a multi websites in magento 2. I have a google it regarding this,but none of the source/procedure didn't provide the path to create multi website/store.

Comment: You can also set up multi site switcher into front end like language switcher and store switcher .. refer this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39290073/how-to-setup-magento-2-website-switcher

Comment: Please check this link... and its working fine.
[Click here for example](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/223152/create-multi-website-in-magento-2?noredirect=1#comment310303_223152)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Created multi-website in Magento, Steps to create a multistore in admin panel is same as like in magento1.x. Don't forget to change the base url and secure url for the new website/store. Once made changes in admin panel follow the below steps,

1. Create a new folder in magento root and copy the `index.php` and `.htaccess` files from magento root to new folder.
2. Edit the `index.php` which is in new folder

**Replace:**

```
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */

$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');

$bootstrap->run($app);
```

**With:**

```
 $params = $_SERVER;
    
 $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'newstore'; //Webite code as same in admin panel
    
 $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';
    
 $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
    
 /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */

 $app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');

 $bootstrap->run($app);
```

And also update bootstrap.php include path as below,

**Replace:**

```
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
```

**With:**

```
require __DIR__ . '/../app/bootstrap.php';
```

3. Create simlinks inside the new folder

   ln -s /home/example/example.com/html/app/ app

   ln -s /home/example/example.com/html/lib/ lib

   ln -s /home/example/example.com/html/pub/ pub

   ln -s /home/example/example.com/html/var/ var

Refer [this](https://docs.nexcess.net/article/how-to-configure-magento-2-storefronts.html)

Please clear the `var/generation, var/cache, and pub/static` files and do the static content deployment.

Comment: I think we have to copy `.htaccess` also (together with `index.php`) from the root to the new folder.

Comment: can you setup multistores without hardcoding values in index.php or htaccess using add store codes to urls? seems to not work on magento2

Comment: Have you tried doing this with the suggested configuration for production environments and pointing the webroot to [Magento root]/pub?

Comment: Do you guys have had any issue applying the same custom theme to both website? Mine the second website is loading assets from ../en_US/... instead of ../en_GB/.. any idea what could be ?

Comment: Try deploy on specific theme with language code

Answer (score 4):

thanks to [this resource](http://www.magikcommerce.com/blog/configure-nginx-single-magento-instance-multi-store/#)

in Magento backend, go to Stores > All Stores
Create here your architecture with different websites/store/storeview
Note carefully the website codes, for instance,

- USA store has code : us, and will be accessed by www.store.com
- French store has code : fr, and will be accessed by www.store.fr
- Spanish store has code : es, and will be accessed by www.store.es

in your Nginx config file (most likely in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled folder)
add at the top of the config file :

```
map $HTTP_HOST $mage_run_code {
www.store.com us;
www.store.fr fr;
www.store.es es;
}
```

then, in the `server` block, add the declaration to listen to the 3 domains :

```
server {
 listen 80;
 server_name www.store.com www.store.fr www.store.es;

// whatever other config you get...
}
```

last, in the php config (the block starting with `location ~ \. php $ {`), add

```
fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_TYPE website;
fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_CODE $mage_run_code;
```

before the line (you will normally see other lines starting with `fastcgi_param` )

```
 include        fastcgi_params;
```

save your config file, restart your Nginx server et voila.

Answer (score 2):

**RTFM**
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/multi-site/ms_over.html

> Contents

- Introduction to multiple Magento stores and websites
- Configure Magento
- Set values for **`MAGE_RUN_TYPE`** and **`MAGE_RUN_CODE`**

Answer (score 1):

Simple way tested on magento 2.2.5

Create a domain alias on your server example domain2.com

Edit index.php file in magento root

```
try {
    require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo <<<HTML
<div style="font:12px/1.35em arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">
    <div style="margin:0 0 25px 0; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;">
        <h3 style="margin:0;font-size:1.7em;font-weight:normal;text-transform:none;text-align:left;color:#2f2f2f;">
        Autoload error</h3>
    </div>
    <p>{$e->getMessage()}</p>
</div>
HTML;
    exit(1);
}

$params = $_SERVER;
$customstore = array(
    'www.main.com'=>'main_website', // Website, Store or Storeview Code
    'www.domian2.com'=>'domain2_website'     // Website, Store or Storeview Code
    );
if(isset($customstore[$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']]))
    $websitecode = $customstore[$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']];
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = isset($websitecode) ? $websitecode : '';
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';//use website or store or view 
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');
$bootstrap->run($app);
```

Comment: I am trying to create multi-website locally (Centos - Nginx) But getting error in Nginx configuration. Any help thanks https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/315027/57334 @Altravista thanks

Comment: Thank you it is working for me in 2.4.2

Answer (score 0):

There are 6 steps to implement multiple website or store on the Magento2 site.

Step 1: Create a Root Category

Step 2: Create a new website

Step 3: Create a new store

Step 4: Create store views

Step 5: Configure the Store URL

Step 6: Map the vhost to work with Magento 2

Comment: I have read this : https://www.thecoachsmb.com/multiple-website-and-multistore-in-magento-2-on-localhost-xampp-windows/

Comment: I'm using apache server in ubuntu system, so how can i set host and domain for second website?  can you please guide me.