# Magento 2 Multi website

Tags: magento2, php, magento-2.1, multi-website

I am working on magento 2 and try to create multi web site.

Web site created properly but JS and CSS not loading properly for **www.example.com/doc1** and **www.example.com/doc2**. For **www.example.com** JS and CSS are working fine.

Site folder structure is bellow

```
/htdocs/  www.example.com  [magento root]
/htdocs/doc1/  www.example.com/doc1 [index.php and .htaccess]
/htdocs/doc2/  www.example.com  [index.php and .htaccess]
```

index.php for www.example.com/doc1

```
    <?php
    try {
        require __DIR__ . '/../app/bootstrap.php';
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        echo <<<HTML
    <div style="font:12px/1.35em arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">
        <div style="margin:0 0 25px 0; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;">
            <h3 style="margin:0;font-size:1.7em;font-weight:normal;text-transform:none;text-align:left;color:#2f2f2f;">
            Autoload error</h3>
        </div>
        <p>{$e->getMessage()}</p>
    </div>
    HTML;
        exit(1);
    }

$params = $_SERVER;
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'doc1'; //Webite code as same in admin panel
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website'; 
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');
$bootstrap->run($app);
```

and .htaccess file is here. I have not change any thing in .htaccess file its default magento 2 file copy from root.

```
# All explanations you could find in .htaccess.sample file
DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_value memory_limit 768M
    php_value max_execution_time 18000
    php_flag session.auto_start off
    php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_php7.c>
    php_value memory_limit 768M
    php_value max_execution_time 18000
    php_flag session.auto_start off
    php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_security.c>
    SecFilterEngine Off
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    SSLOptions StdEnvVars
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
    RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
</IfModule>
    AddDefaultCharset Off
    AddType 'text/html; charset=UTF-8' html
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/html A0
    ExpiresByType text/plain A0
</IfModule>
    RedirectMatch 403 /\.git
    <Files composer.json>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files composer.lock>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files .gitignore>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files .htaccess>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files .htaccess.sample>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files .php_cs>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files .travis.yml>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files CHANGELOG.md>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files CONTRIBUTING.md>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files COPYING.txt>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files Gruntfile.js>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files LICENSE.txt>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files LICENSE_AFL.txt>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files nginx.conf.sample>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files package.json>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files php.ini.sample>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files README.md>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files magento_umask>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
ErrorDocument 404 /pub/errors/404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /pub/errors/404.php
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=edge"
    <FilesMatch "\.(appcache|atom|bbaw|bmp|crx|css|cur|eot|f4[abpv]|flv|geojson|gif|htc|ico|jpe?g|js|json(ld)?|m4[av]|manifest|map|mp4|oex|og[agv]|opus|otf|pdf|png|rdf|rss|safariextz|svgz?|swf|topojson|tt[cf]|txt|vcard|vcf|vtt|webapp|web[mp]|webmanifest|woff2?|xloc|xml|xpi)$">
        Header unset X-UA-Compatible
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

I have setup store view url like bellow
[image]

Please check my error screenshot here.

[image]

Let me know if any suggestion is there.
I have added simlinks

```
ln -s /home/example/example.com/html/app/ app 

 ln -s /home/example/example.com/html/lib/ lib 

 ln -s /home/example/example.com/html/pub/ pub 

 ln -s /home/example/example.com/html/var/ var
```

Comment: Did you follow like this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94855/create-multi-website-stores-in-magento-2

Comment: @saravanavelu yes i have follow that. Please check my edited answer

Comment: Did you tried static content deploy and cleared the cache/generation files?

Comment: @saravanavelu i have tried static content deploy and cleared cache lots of time but not working for me can you suggest some more solution

Comment: whether url for new website static view files still have docs1?

Comment: @saravanavelu No i have try to do as per your suggestion but still not found any solution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52424/discussion-between-saravanavelu-and-jalpesh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, change Base URL for static view and User Media files to the base default url:

[image]

**EDIT:**
We can create the symbolic links: [Create Multi Website/Stores in magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94855/create-multi-website-stores-in-magento-2)

Comment: It is not necessary to set the URLs for static view files and media for the multiwebsite. It is enough to set the simulinks

Comment: @saravanavelu i have created simulinks but not work for me

Comment: @saravanavelu yes, you may be right! I need to check again.