# Magento 2 Multi Store with Sub-domain for B2B

Tags: magento2, multistore, b2b

I need to create a new store for my e-commerce (not a new website, not a new store front) for B2B.

Now, my e-commerce is active on mobiroloshop.com (B2C) and I want the new store on b2b.mobiroloshop.com.

I've followed several tutorials but still have problems. If I create an alias (parked domain) on cPanel for B2B, when I type b2b.mobiroloshop.com,

I'm redirected to mobiroloshop.com. I tried both to change .htaccess file (following step-by-step this tutorial https://www.cloudways.com/blog/create-and-configure-multistore-magento-2/) and to use a switch statement on my index.php (to switch B2B or B2C based on $_SERVER content).

Can someone please help me with this struggling issue?

[image: This is my Magento Stores configuration]

My Magento store configuration.

Comment: https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-setup-multiple-stores-magento-2.html

Comment: I tried this too, but without setting subdomain the browser responds with "Server not found" @AnkitShah

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94855/create-multi-website-stores-in-magento-2
https://magecomp.com/blog/setup-multi-store-in-magento-2/
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/multi-site/ms_over.html

Comment: Tried everything in there, I still have this "redirect" issue. If I type b2b.mobiroloshop.com it goes to mobiroloshop.com (b2c store) @AnkitShah

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. What's missing is the environment variable.

Add to your .htaccess file

```
SetEnvIf Host b2b\.mobiroloshop\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=b2b
SetEnvIf Host b2b\.mobiroloshop\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store
```

If your server is Nginx, check:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/multi-site/ms_nginx.html

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem setting the correct envioroment variables and using de env_mode of apache.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName msite1.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/magedemo/pub

    <Directory /var/www/magedemo/pub/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName msite2.domain.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/magedemo/pub

    <Directory /var/www/magedemo/pub/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    SetEnv MAGE_RUN_CODE "s2"
    SetEnv MAGE_RUN_TYPE "store"
</VirtualHost>
```

The code "s2" is the code configured for the webview.

This is my configuration using Magento 2.1.7:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is possible through your index.php

*for apache use index.php and for nginx use pub/index.php*

example switch including development suffix support:

```
if(!isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) || !$_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) {
    if (preg_match('/^(.+)\.(developmentsuffix.com)/', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $match)) {
        $website = $match[1];
    } else {
        $website = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    }

    switch ($website) {
        case "example.com":
        case "www.example.com":
            $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] = "website_code";
            $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] = "website";
            break;

        case "sub.example.com":
            $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] = "website_code2";
            $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] = "website";
            break;

        default:
            $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] = "website_code";
            $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] = "website";
    }
}
```

put the code just above this line:

> $params = $_SERVER;

and don't forget to set the correct base urls in the Magento Configuration