# Magento 2 multi store error

Tags: magento-2.1

I am running Magento 2.1.4 and I have followed the steps located here: `https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94855/create-multi-website-stores-in-magento-2`

But when I try to go to the url of my second store I am getting this error...

```
Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/myuser/public_html/mainstore/secondstore/app/bootstrap.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php56/pear') in /home/myuser/public_html/mainstore/secondstore/index.php on line 22
```

It looks like it is not finding `/home/myuser/public_html/mainstore/secondstore/app/bootstrap.php` but I have created the symlink to the 'app' folder

Any help or pointers would be appreciated please
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Revert Your changes and follow:

1. Create store view, store and website.
2. In admin add urls for websites/ sotres.
3. Add your urls to apache to vh (can be added as alias)
4. Add rewrites to your main `.htaccess` similar to  (but change it to your url and websites/stores code):

> ```
> // This is for base website with url www.magento.test.pl  
> SetEnvIf Host www\.magento\.test\.pl MAGE_RUN_CODE=base  
> SetEnvIf Host www\.magento\.test\.pl MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website  
> SetEnvIf Host ^magento\.test\.pl MAGE_RUN_CODE=base  
> SetEnvIf Host ^magento\.test\.pl MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website  
>
> // This is for custom website with custom code - one, with url www.one.magento.test.pl  
> SetEnvIf Host www\.one\.magento\.test\.pl MAGE_RUN_CODE=one  
> SetEnvIf Host www\.one\.magento\.test\.pl MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website  
> SetEnvIf Host ^one\.magento\.test\.pl MAGE_RUN_CODE=one  
> SetEnvIf Host ^one\.magento\.test\.pl MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
> ```

Comment: Thank you - please could you expand on step 3? I am on a shared server with no direct access to apache. When you say can be added as alias does that get around it? Sorry I am not familiar with this

Comment: If you don't have access to apache/nginx, just write to your admin for add alias for your store

Comment: it is a shared environment so making changes to apache/nginx is not possible. Is there no other way to set multistores up or do we have to have a dedicated server? Thanks