# Create Multi Websties/Stores issue on Magento 2

Tags: magento2, multistore, redirect, store-view

I Have created form backend a new Website with his own Store and Store View

I have already set for my new **Store View** : **Base URLs** -  **Base URL** and  **Base Link URL** with the new link: for example :  http://clubshop.testwswear.com/ (same value for both fields) and the same thing set for the  **Base URLs (Secure)**

After this I have followed this steps form this answer: [Create Multi Website/Stores in magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94855/create-multi-website-stores-in-magento-2(the) accepted one )  and after all, when I try to access my new link it redirect me on the defaul store view link.

Does anyone know what I did  wrong? or why it redirect me all the time?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem by adding in my `index.php`:

```
$host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$params = $_SERVER;
if (strpos($host,'clubshop')) {
    $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'web_shop';
    $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';
} else {
    $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'base';
    $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';
}
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');
$bootstrap->run($app);
```

So my new shop web site contain the name `clubshop` found in backend at **Web Site Information** ->**code**