# How to set one domain for each language

Tags: magento2, configuration, language, websites

I need to redirect my magento to another domain after changing the language.

Example:

- After select English - switch domain to mydomain.co.uk
- After select Czech Republic - switch domain to mydomain.cz

Anyone know how to do ?

@Prince

Can you explain me more ? I have two languages set up and a working store switcher.

When I switch language then I get url:

From **EN** to **CZ**:

```
http://myweb.com/?___store=cz&___from_store=en
```

FROM **CZ** TO **EN**:

```
http://myweb.com/?___store=en&___from_store=cz
```

**only now instead:**

```
http://myweb.com/?___store=cz&___from_store=en
```

**I want redirect:**

```
http://myweb.cz/
```

EDIT2:
I have created new website_Cz:
[image]

and set language **cz** for new website

but now I cannot see this language on frontend switcher.

[image]

I know I'm still doing it wrong, I will be grateful if you can help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your requirements, you have to create two websites with :

- one language for each website
- one domaine for each website

To switch between the two languages, you have to add some storeswitcher or a dropdown input.

**EDIT:**

You have this `?___store=...` in your **urls** because you are using just **one website** with different storeview ! this is why i told you to use **two websites** and you create and set just **one store** and **one view** for each website, you set `en` language for the first website and `cz` for the the second.

**nb:** the languages you set them in the **store view** `Stores -> All stores -> Storeview` code and in **Locale** `Stores -> Configuration -> General`

[More informations](https://amasty.com/knowledge-base/change-default-language-in-magento-2.html)

**EDIT 2:**
Please read my first reply :

> "To switch between the two languages, you have to add some
>   storeswitcher or a dropdown input."

The **store switcher** appear JUST when you have 2 store views under the current website that you are viewing.

Since you have only **one store view** for each website this doesn't appear.

You can Follow these tuto to set well your website config in admin and server part.

[Create Multi Website/Stores in magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94855/create-multi-website-stores-in-magento-2)

http://www.dckap.com/blog/how-to-setup-multiple-stores-in-magento2/

Comment: @Price, I have updated topic. Can you check? Thanks.

Comment: Ok I set domain on configuration --> WEB

Comment: I saw your update, you have this `?___store=...` in your urls because you are using just `one website`with different storeview ! this is why i told you to use two websites with for each 1 store and one view.

Comment: please look my edit 2

Comment: Ok, did you solve your problem ?

Comment: Prince, Can you accept our order to configure this?

Comment: our order ... ?

Comment: Prince, if you can please contact with me on email address I sent you.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what kind of server you're running you'll have to change your htaccess or your nginx settings.

First in the backend, specify your base urls at `store > configuration > web`

For the english storeview set `http://domain.co.uk`
For the Czech storeview set `http://domain.cz`

For Apache: 
Then in your .htaccess set these lines:

```
SetEnv MAGE_RUN_TYPE store
SetEnvIf Host ^.*domain[-\.]co.uk MAGE_RUN_CODE=en
SetEnvIf Host ^.*domain[-\.]cz MAGE_RUN_CODE=cz
```

For Nginx

```
    map $host $storecode {
       hostnames;
       .domain.cz cz;
       .domain.co.uk en;
    }

    map $host $storetype {
       hostnames;
       default store;
    }
```