# CSS and JS are not calling for Multi- website in Magento-2.2.4

Tags: css, multistore, magento2.2.4

I am working on Magento-2.2.4.

So, my url is as follows : http://puppetkart.com/ and on Luma theme.

**My requirement is as follows :**

1. I have created second website and store and store view for this newly created website in admin panel. My new website is http://vizag.puppetkart.com/  And added this url at Base url section for this new website.
2. I have created sub domain and managed the DNS also. Edited the `index.php` which is in new folder

**Replaced:**

```
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */

$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');

$bootstrap->run($app);
```

**With:**

```
$params = $_SERVER;

 $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'vizag'; //Webite code as same in admin panel

 $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';

 $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);

 /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */

 $app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');

 $bootstrap->run($app);
```

3. **When i open my new website http://vizag.puppetkart.com/, CSS and js are not calling properly.**

Can anyone please guide me to create multi websites.

Comment: You can use the sub directory method. Like hy forhyderabad, and in their use the htaccess, index.php and symlinks to root for other directories. 

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94855/create-multi-website-stores-in-magento-2

Comment: Can we work without creating new folders like as axample you'he told?@LAW

Comment: You can use server to point the domain, and set domain using index.php on root

Comment: @LAW, I have pointed the domain. please check once my updated description

Comment: Seems like correct, try to clear cache, and clear static content. If still not solved, shared the url which is getting formed in sub-domain for css files

Comment: @TejaBhagavanKollepara Any help with the same thread Multi_website https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/315027/57334 Thanks

Comment: Its works for me thank you so much.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try updating the following fields with that of your main domain?
under

```
Stores->Configuration->General->Web-><your new store>

Secure Base URL for Static View Files (eg: (http://yourmaindomain.com/static/)

Secure Base URL for User Media Files (http://yourmaindomain.com/media/)
```

Because your media is now trying to fetch from a directory (pub/static) that is relative to your new base url which does not exist. If you ask Magento to fetch your media and static files (css/JS) from parent site it should work.

Try this and confirm (in view source) from where the media/static resources are fetching.

Comment: You should have set that in the store scope. Now you have to delete that entry from core_config_data to get the admin interface back normal. And then switch to the store you want to get the change affected and update the urls.