# How to create website

Tags: magento2, multistore, multi-website

I have created another website name called submainwebsite in admin side. i have configured all those.

Then i had created a folder within root folder ex: www.example.com/store 
Inside that i have created index.php and .htaccess file.

when i run the site means i am getting like this https://prnt.sc/pgcvhg.

can anyone help this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please refer this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94855/create-multi-website-stores-in-magento-2

Comment: You have to set pub, media folder path to root folder's pub

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Admin->Stores->Configuration->General->Web`

And set as below

> Base URL for Static View Files -> baseUrl/pub/static/
>
> Base URL for User Media Files  -> baseUrl/pub/media/