# Magento 2.3 - After setup Multi-website CSS unknown error - LEMP (Centos 7 - Nginx)

Tags: error, css, nginx, magento2.3.4, localhost

After configure multi website using https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/117930/57334 css not loading.

Note: My main website working, multi Website only getting this error.

[image]